# How to use server side data in client side-service portal?

Tags: servicenow

I have one array called `data.list` in server side. I am trying to use it in client side by calling like this

```
c.data.list
```

When I print it in server side it returns correct data. But in client side it returns `undefined`.

How can I use that array in client side?

Please give some ideas guys.

Answer (score 1):

So in Servicenow, on the server side code you just refer to `data`.  In the client you then can access `data` via `c.data`

Here's an example from my instance;

Server side code;

```
(function() {
    /* populate the 'data' object */
    /* e.g., data.table = $sp.getValue('table'); */
    var sysId = $sp.getParameter("sys_id");
    var spLimit = parseInt(gs.getProperty('glide.service_portal.stream_entry_limit'),10);
    var ga = GlideAggregate('sys_journal_field');
    ga.addQuery('element_id', sysId);
    ga.addAggregate('COUNT');
    ga.query();
    gs.print(ga.getEncodedQuery());
    if (ga.next()) {
        var count = parseInt(ga.getAggregate('COUNT'), 10);
        data.count = count;
        data.exceedsLimit = count > spLimit;
    }
})();
```

HTML;

```
<div id="show-conversation-limit">
    <!--Exceeds limit: {{c.data.exceedsLimit}}
    Count: {{c.data.count}}-->
    <div ng-if="data.exceedsLimit" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        Due to the quantity of comments, the some comments have been removed
        starting with the oldest.
    </div>
</div>
```